# How do I set the 'Description' with PayPal's 'Buy Now' button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway

[image]

I have this image where I can set the Amount but I cannot set the Description:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
 method="post"   target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="moneytreelondon@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">

  <input id="total_price_and_postage_rate" type="hidden"
  name="amount" value<%=r.total_price_and_postage_rate_no_commission%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
 <input type="hidden" name="bn" 
   value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Refund">
  <img alt="" [enter image description here][1]border="0" 
   src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"    
   width="1"    height="1">
  </form>
```

How do I set the 'Descriptions'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the descriptions with this form tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Desc">
```

Omitting the `item_name` and `amount` tags will let your customers make manual inputs in the PayPal checkout page

[image]

Comment: I know you can do that but I want this field to be populated automatically like with the 'Amount' field.

Comment: <input id="total_price_and_postage_rate" type="hidden"
  name="amount" value<%=r.total_price_and_postage_rate_no_commission%>">

Comment: As per my answer, put your pre-set value into this tag `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Desc">` will make it auto populated in the checkout page, just like what you did to `amount`